# How to assign angularjs value to jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using Jquery library for slider which work properly when assign static value. but when used angularjs then its not working.

here is my code -

```
<div id="featured" ng-repeat="catagory in AllCatagory">

            <h2 class="featured_title">{{catagory.catagoryName}}</h2>
            <div id="slider{{$index}}">

                <div class="thumbelina-but horiz left disabled"><</div>

                <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

                    <ul class="thumbelina" style="left: 0px;">

                        <li style="display: inline-block;" data-ng-repeat="VideoListAgriculture in AirToAir track by $index">
                            <div>
                                <div class="con_top_bar">
                                    <h4 class="con_title">{{VideoListAgriculture.Title.substring(0,15)}}
                                    <span ng-if="VideoListAgriculture.Title.length>15">..</span></h4>
                                    <h4 class="time">{{VideoListAgriculture.ViewCount}} <img src="images/vuz-logo-wht.png" width="25" height="" style="border:none;"></h4>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="/editor?id={{VideoListAgriculture._id}}">
                                    <img src="{{VideoListAgriculture.Thumbnail}}" width="302" height="162"></a>
                                <div class="bottom_bar">
                                    <p class="left">{{VideoListAgriculture.Categories}}</p>
                                    <p class="right">{{VideoListAgriculture.Duration}}</p>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="thumbelina-but horiz right disabled">˃</div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

And jquery code ,

```
$('#slider0').Thumbelina({
                $bwdBut:$('#slider0 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
                $fwdBut:$('#slider0 .right')    // Selector to right button.
            }); 
$('#slider1').Thumbelina({
                $bwdBut:$('#slider1 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
                $fwdBut:$('#slider1 .right')    // Selector to right button.
            });  
            $('#slider2').Thumbelina({
                $bwdBut:$('#slider2 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
                $fwdBut:$('#slider2 .right')    // Selector to right button.
            });  
            $('#slider3').Thumbelina({
                $bwdBut:$('#slider3 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
                $fwdBut:$('#slider3 .right')    // Selector to right button.
            });  
            $('#slider4').Thumbelina({
                $bwdBut:$('#slider4 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
                $fwdBut:$('#slider4 .right')    // Selector to right button.
            });  
            $('#slider5').Thumbelina({
                $bwdBut:$('#slider5 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
                $fwdBut:$('#slider5 .right')    // Selector to right button.
            });
```

But It's working when ng-repeat is not here. can anyone give any solution for this problem.

Comment: Where's the directive that wraps that jQuery code?

Comment: I'm not used any directive.

Comment: That might be a problem.

Comment: Can you please make a plunker of it , so we can pay with it and solve your issue

Comment: Oh! It solved finally using angular directive. Thank you.